# My (software) service is continuously removed after a windows 10 update on a notebook/ client

Tags: c#, xml, windows-10

I have a service running on my clients notebooks which is used by my software (Xmlservice)
I install this service from a setup project as an output file.
When Microsoft releases there update (for example 1803 or later) this hosted service will be removed from the client and my software doesn't work anymore. I have to do a new install from my software.
This is how my service is hosted:

```
    void OpenHost()
    {
       const string strAdrHttp = "http://localhost:port/XmlService"
       Uri[] adrbase = { new Uri(strAdrHttp) };

            _svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SealedClassinHere), adrbase);

            var mBehave = new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true };
            _svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(mBehave);

            var httpb = new WSHttpBinding
            {
                ReaderQuotas =
                {
                    MaxArrayLength = 10485760, MaxStringContentLength = 2524288
                }, //max 10MB compressed transport
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 2524288,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2524288,
                Security = { Mode = SecurityMode.None, Message = { ClientCredentialType = 
                MessageCredentialType.None } }
            };

            _svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), httpb, strAdrHttp);

            _svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange),
            MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");

            _svcHost.Open();
     }
```

and code for serviceinstaller:

```
   [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ServiceInstaller : Installer
    {
        public ServiceInstaller()
        {
            serviceProcessInstaller1 = new ServiceProcessInstaller 
           {Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem};
            serviceInstaller1 = new ServiceInstaller
            {
                ServiceName = "XmlService",
                DisplayName = "XmlService",
                Description = "WCF XmlService Hosting *project.Service",
                StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic
            };
            Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller1);
            Installers.Add(serviceInstaller1);
        }

        private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, 
         InstallEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```